# jquery word warp and remove wrap not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some words pass from search, I want to wrap them with a `div` then click one link, remove the outer `wrap`, but my code not worked for `wrap` and `unwrap`. What is wrong?

```
<?php $_GET['search']='this is a text'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js" ></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var words = '<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>';
        $(words).wrap('<div id="words" />');
        $('body').append(words);
        $('#click').click(function(){
            $(words).unwrap('<div id="words" />');
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <a id="click">remove me</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

words can't be a string wrap only works on a jquery object, or a dom element.

try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = 'this is your search string';
    words = '<div id="words">'+words+'</div>'; // wrap it, basically creating the string
    $('body').append(words);
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('#words').replaceWith($('#words').get(0).childNodes); // get the words outsde of it again, unwrap only works on the inner element.
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <a id="click">remove me</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Point 1 - you can wrap only DOM element, as stated above

Point 2 - before you wrap, you have to add it to the DOM, otherwise there'll be no access 
to added 'div'

Point 3 - if you write $(words) and $(words) two times, these are not the same object!

You should do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('<span></span>').text('words words words');
    words.wrap('<div id="words"></div>');
    $('body').append(words);
    $('#click').click(function(){
         words.unwrap('<div id="words" />');
    });
});
```

Also check [this link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEacV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`words` must be selector, not a string

Answer (score 0):

You wrap the elements before adding them to the document and words must be a DOM element.

You might try to use `$('body').append()` on `<div id="words">your_php_result</div>` directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's your selector that doesn't work. You end up doing `$('this is a text')`, which will search for a `text` element in a structure like this:

```
<this>
  <is>
    <a>
      <text></text>
    </a>
  </is>
</this>
```

Of course there are no such elements, so the result is an empty jQuery object.

If you want to wrap words in a text, you would have to loop through all relevant elements on the page, get their content using `.text()` or `.html()`, find words in the text and replace them with the HTML code that wraps the words, and put the text back in the elements.

Generally this is easier and more robust to do in the server side code.